# svelte and supabase endpoints

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

For supabase and sveltekit. which is better for fetching the data.

using the stores or using endpoints?

im trying to understand why the endpoints are so important. besides lessing down on the boiler plate code for context module, what are the benefits?

Comment: Help me out here, trying to understand what you mean. Does the question basically boil down to whether you should fetch data from Supabase via an endpoint on the server or via a store on the client?

Comment: Yea. So for example im using supabase. I know i can fetch data from end point but i cant use await block however i can fetch from store. I learnt that if i fetch from store im fetching from the client and that would be a bad user experience. But should i also update data from end points as well or can i use stores for that